# Could you use magnets to orient in space?

Tags: artificial-satellite, attitude, nanosatellite

If I had a tiny satellite with a magnet orbiting Earth (or another body with a magnetic field), could I use this magnet to adjust my attitude?

I'm thinking it could be used in sort of the same way as one would use a reaction wheel. Just turn the magnet to where it is not aligned with the field, and wait for it to turn the whole satellite with it.

Would  it be more plausible if the satellite was in geostationary orbit?

Comment: perhaps a *semi-duplicate* of [Could an articulated permanent magnet work as a low-power cubesat magnetotorquer? Problems?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17641/could-an-articulated-permanent-magnet-work-as-a-low-power-cubesat-magnetotorquer) I think it's a great question, and a great idea! Have a look at this and see if it answers your question. If you need something else answered, or want to explore some new aspect of the question, feel free to adjust your question, or to ask a new one and link back here.

Comment: You've asked about an electromagnet, whereas my question is about a permanent magnet which wouldn't need any power to generate the field, and for a cubesat could have a *much stronger, sustained field* than a solar-powered electromagnet.

Comment: Buy one online, ready to install in your satellite for only €8000 today: https://www.cubesatshop.com/product/isis-magnetorquer-board/

Comment: [Directly related](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/passive-attitude-stabilization-with-magnets-are-there-studies-based-on-actual?rq=1), and also [less related, more about "maximal output of magnetic torque"](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2032/could-magnetorquers-be-used-on-the-iss?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a [magnetotorquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetorquer)

> A magnetorquer or magnetic torquer (also known as torque rod) is a satellite system for attitude control, detumbling, and stabilization built from electromagnetic coils. The magnetorquer creates a magnetic dipole that interfaces with an ambient magnetic field, usually Earth's, so that the counter-forces produced provide useful torque.

The article goes on to discuss the limitations of these devices and specifically mentions:

> A broader disadvantage is the dependence on Earth's magnetic field strength, making this approach unsuitable for deep space missions, and also more suitable for low Earth orbits as opposed to higher ones like the geosynchronous.

Comment: The OP is asking about *articulating the magnet* "...used in sort of the same way as one would use a reaction wheel. *Just turn the magnet* to where it is not aligned with the field, and wait for it to turn the whole satellite with it." Are there articulated magnetotorquers? Maybe there are, I've always assumed they were controlled by adjusting the current in different oriented loops. I'd love to read about an articulated magnetotorquer!

Comment: If you can find one, you may be able to add another answer to [Could an articulated permanent magnet work as a low-power cubesat magnetotorquer? Problems?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/17641/12102)